# Windows 7 16GB RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, motherboard: Asus P7P55D-E, processor: intel core i7 2.8GHz. I bought 4 sticks of Nanya-Elixir RAM (DDR3 4096MB 1333MHz UDIMM, CL9). After installing them, windows detects 16GB of ram, but says that only 8GB is usable :(. I thought BIOS update would help, but it only raised the usable space by 10MB -- before, windows reported 7,99GB as usable.

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/221333/how-can-i-get-my-64-bit-computer-to-recognize-all-of-my-ram/221337#221337

Comment: Dupe indeed, reinserting fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check (and double check) that they are inserted fully.

It's common for sticks to not quite be seated properly. Modern motherboards+win7 are able to spot this and simply report the ram as "unusable".